# Invalid number of arguments during code refactoring scipy SLSQP

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize an objective function using `scipy.optimize.minimize.`

Initially, I kept getting the error

`TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the - operator, is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor, the ^ operator, or the logical_xor function instead.`

After looking for a solution, I found out code refactoring was needed in my `scipy\optimize\slsqp.py` file. I changed the `-` operator to np.subtract() as shown below,

`jac[i] = (func(*((x0+dx,)+args)) - f0)/epsilon   # This was the error line`

`jac[i] = np.subtract((func(*((x0+dx,)+args)), f0))/epsilon  # which I changed to this`

but now I keep getting the error,
`ValueError: invalid number of arguments` on this exact same line

I don't understand, as I've tried np.subtract with example arguments, and it seems to work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you get that `TypeError` in the line that you indicated, it seems to imply that your objective function `func` is returning a value with type `bool`.  Have you checked that `func` actually returns floating point values, as expected by the minimizers in SciPy?

Answer (score 0):

With a boolean dtype array:

```
In [131]: x = np.ones(4, bool)
```

Your first error:

```
In [132]: x-x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-132-966d70d4047a>", line 1, in <module>
    x-x
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

Why are `func` and `f0` boolean?

As for your second error, you have extra ():

```
In [133]: np.subtract((x,x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-133-d710885b85a3>", line 1, in <module>
    np.subtract((x,x))
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

With the correct arguments (2), you still have the boolean error:

```
In [134]: np.subtract(x,x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-134-76169c24bdd5>", line 1, in <module>
    np.subtract(x,x)
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```